# What is equivalent of Linux's 'free' command on FreeBSD v8.1

Tags: linux, memory, freebsd, porting, free-command

What is equivalent of Linux's 'free' command on FreeBSD v8.1?

I am calling 'free' from my application and reporting the results in my application's log file.  What would be the replacement when porting to FreeBSD v8.1?

Here is a sample run of 'free' on Linux:

```
[centos4x32 ~] free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        774452     733044      41408          0      98040     328880
-/+ buffers/cache:     306124     468328
Swap:      2031608        224    2031384
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- `vmstat` has default output which is similar in nature and takes many options that give extremely detailed information, eg `vmstat -m`
- `swapinfo` would cover the swap part
- `top -d1` causes top to print one screen and exit, and the banner is very similar to `free`. Use `top -d1 | head -n 7` to see only the banner

Comment: On *Linux* the one-screen option is `top -n1`.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe `freecolor` command is a choice. Install it:

```
# cd /usr/ports/sysutils/freecolor
# make install clean
```

Use it:

```
# freecolor
Physical  : [#################################..] 94%   (1907820/2018396)
Swap      : [###################################] 100%  (1048540/1048540)
# freecolor -m -o
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1971        107       1863          0          0          0
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

Please refer [FreeBSD find out RAM size Including Total Amount of Free and Used Memory Size](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-command-to-get-ram-information/).

Answer (score 10):

`vmstat -s` gives some more human-readable or script-parseable information, including listing the page size.  Otherwise, it gives output in numbef of pages. With no options, `vmstat` gives a brief summary.

The `vmstat` command also exists on NetBSD.

Answer (score 3):

just use old good **htop**

install htop

```
 pkg install htop
```

to run

```
htop
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option:

```
# vmstat fre

procs      memory      page                      faults         cpu
 r b w     avm    fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr  sr   in   sy   cs us sy id
 0 0 0  13475M    24M   689   1   2   0   344 394 14693 37734 60809  7 43 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script.

```
# fetch http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/scripts/freebsd-memory.pl.txt
# mv freebsd-memory.pl.txt /usr/local/bin/free
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/free
```

source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-command-to-get-ram-information/